# Десериализация JSON в коллекцию

Tags: c#, json

Есть вот такой json. Все объекты одного типа, но выдает их не массивов.
Как можно десерилизовать в коллекцию. Пользуюсь Newtonsoft.Json.

```
{
"rgInventory": {
    "3747947135": {
        "id": "3747947135",
        "classid": "1333125886",
        "instanceid": "257420333",
        "amount": "1",
        "pos": 1
    },
    "3830672348": {
        "id": "3830672348",
        "classid": "771156314",
        "instanceid": "679090853",
        "amount": "1",
        "pos": 2
    },
    "4310878346": {
        "id": "4310878346",
        "classid": "771156819",
        "instanceid": "57944754",
        "amount": "1",
        "pos": 3
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ в английской версии сайта.

```
var jsonobj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        foreach (var child in jsonobj["rgDescriptions"].Children())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item ID: {0}", child.First()["id"]);
        }
```